# How to get the text of a column header if a cell of a QAbstractTableModel is clicked?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a `TableModel` that implements the `QAbstractTableModel` class. I added some flags to make the table cells editable. If I click on any cell, I need to obtain the header text of the column.

In the `setData` function I get the index of the cell that was clicked, I realize that I can get the `row` and `column` and also the text of the cell, using `QModelIndex`.

```
bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &val, int role) {
    if (role == Qt::EditRole) {
        auto cellText = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        std::cout << "row number: " << index.row() << " col number: " << index.column() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "indexText: " << cellText.toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the following table, for example, if I click on cell `b2` I need to obtain the column title: `"Column B"`

```
-----------------------------------
Column A  |  Column B  |  Column C 
-----------------------------------
a1        |    b1      |    c1
a2        |    b2      |    c2
a3        |    b3      |    c3
```

There is a way to obtain the header of any index, maybe with the number of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> click on cell , obtain the column title.

I connected `QTableView::clicked` signal.

I override `headerData` function.

```
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QHeaderView>
class Table :public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const
    {
        return 8;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const
    {
        return 5;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
    {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        {
            return "r=" + QString::number(index.row()) + ",c=" + QString::number(index.column());
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE virtual QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
        int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
    {
        if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role==Qt::DisplayRole)
        {
            return "head=" + QString::number(section);
        }
        return QVariant();

    }
};

int main8(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableView view;
    Table tb;
    view.setModel(&tb);
    view.show();
    QObject::connect(&view, &QTableView::clicked, [&](const QModelIndex& index) {
        qDebug()<<"head="<<tb.headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole);
        });
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the `headerData` function and it worked. It's what I'm looking for.